# Averaging blocks of cells in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, average

For reasons that are difficult to explain, I want to average blocks of cells in a pandas dataframe which is sparsely populated with random values. The dataframe will always have sqrt(number of columns x number of indices) values -- and all the rest will be NaN. The values are approximately uniformly distributed so that if I average the right sized block of cells I expect to have one value within each block.

Here's my example. For 100 columns and 100 indices, I have 100 values randomly distributed throughout the dataframe. I expect there to be ~1 value per 10x10 block, with all the others being NaN. How can I turn each 10x10 block into one cell (averaging the 10 columns, 10 indices, and value(s) within it?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

number_of_planes = 100

thicknesses = np.empty(number_of_planes)
cos_thetas = np.empty(number_of_planes)
phis = np.empty(number_of_planes)
for i in range(0,number_of_planes):
    r = 1
    phi = np.random.uniform(0,2*math.pi)
    theta = math.acos(2*np.random.uniform(0.5,1) - 1)
    thickness = np.random.uniform(0,0.4)

    phis[i] = phi
    cos_thetas[i] = math.cos(theta)
    thicknesses[i] = thickness

thick_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=phis, index=cos_thetas)

for i in range(0, len(thicknesses)):
    thick_df.set_value(cos_thetas[i], phis[i], thicknesses[i], takeable=False)

thick_df = thick_df.sort_index(axis=0, ascending=False)
thick_df = thick_df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can reshape into a 4D array splitting each axis into two axes of length `sqrt(len of each axis)` and compute average along the second and fourth axes ignoring the `NaNs` with [`np.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) -

```
arr = thick_df.values.astype(float)
n = int(np.sqrt(number_of_planes))

out = np.nanmean(arr.reshape(n,n,n,n),axis=(1,3))

indx = thick_df.index.values.reshape(-1,n).mean(1)
coln = thick_df.columns.values.reshape(-1,n).mean(1)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, index=indx, columns= coln)
```

Sample run -

```
In [174]: thick_df # number_of_planes = 4
Out[174]: 
          4.550477  5.138694  5.411510 6.123163
0.981987       NaN       NaN  0.393233      NaN
0.565861  0.186647       NaN       NaN      NaN
0.193190       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.11626
0.088382       NaN  0.166189       NaN      NaN

In [175]: df_out
Out[175]: 
          4.844586  5.767337
0.773924  0.186647  0.393233
0.140786  0.166189  0.116260
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, but when I tried to apply it to my code it didn't work. Which part do I need to change to make this work for my 100x100 dataframe?

Comment: @Rebecca Could you elaborate on the didn't work part?  `NaNs` in there or value mismatch? Should have worked without any changes.

Comment: I get the runtime warning saying "Mean of empty slice" and the resulting dataframe looks unchanged.

Comment: @Rebecca To create the output dataframe, you need to use `pd.Dataframe(out)`, where `out = np.nanmean(thick_df.values.astype(float).reshape(n,n,n,n),axis=(1,3))`. On the warning issue, its because there are blocks that have all `NaNs`, so it can't ignore and that's why the warning and the output would be `NaN` for those blocks.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Works perfectly! There are still a few NaNs just because it's not populated truly uniformly but your solution definitely works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops wait, how can I get the averaged indices and columns too? They both just became integers from 0 to 9.

Comment: @Rebecca Do you mean you would have exactly one non NaN value per block? Otherwise I am not sure what would  averaged indices and columns mean? What if that block has all NaN, what must be the  averaged indices and columns?

Comment: I mean the labels! I want to know what the average index and average column for each averaged cell are. The NaN values I mentioned are for the few areas where there were no values in a block -- they're a different thing and not a problem.

Comment: Not quite -- I don't want separate dataframes of the column and index values. I want my output dataframe to have index and column values that are the averages of what they were before. So instead of being 0 to 9, the indices for example would be [average of indices 0-9, average of 10-19, average of 20-29,...] and so on.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so, so much. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
m, n = 10, 10
row_groups = np.arange(len(thick_df.index)) // m
col_groups = np.arange(len(thick_df.columns)) // n

grpd = pd.DataFrame(thick_df.values, row_groups, col_groups)

val = pd.to_numeric(grpd.stack(), 'coerce').groupby(level=[0, 1]).mean().unstack().values
idx = thick_df.index.to_series().groupby(row_groups).mean().values
col = thick_df.columns.to_series().groupby(col_groups).mean().values

pd.DataFrame(val, idx, col)
```

[image]

Comment: Same problem as the above solution -- I need the column and index labels to be the averages of their previous values!